# Poincare lemma for non-smooth differentiable forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes

The Poincare lemma is almost always formulated for differential forms with smooth coefficients (or sometimes for currents that have distributional coefficients). I would like to have it for $C^k$-coefficients. For one dimension everything is fine:
$$0\to \mathbb R \to C^1(\mathbb R) \to C(\mathbb R)\to 0$$
(where the first map assigns the constant function and the second is the derivative) is exact because of the fundamental theorem of calculus. For $\mathbb R^2$ the analogous sequence would be
$$0\to \mathbb R \to C^2(\mathbb R^2) \to C^1(\mathbb R^2)^2\to C(\mathbb R^2)\to 0$$
where the first map again assigns the constant function, the second is the gradient and the third is $d: C^1(\mathbb R^2)^2\to C(\mathbb R^2)$, $(g_1,g_2)\mapsto \partial_2 g_1 - \partial_1 g_2$.
This sequence is exact at the first three spots (the usual proof of the poincare lemma) but I don't see whether it is exact at the last spot, that is, whether $d$ is onto.

(For the same complex with $C^\infty$ (or $\mathscr D'$) instead of $C^k$ surjectivity of $d$ is trivial: For $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ one can just integrate one variable: $g_1(x,y)=\int_0^yh(x,t)dt$ and $g_2=0$ yield $d(g_1,g_2)=h$. However, if $h$ is just continuous there is no reason why $g_1$ should be differentiable w.r.t. $x$.)

---

EDIT. The discussion with Igor (and his updated answer) lead to the simple observation that it would be sufficient to show the surjectivity of $\Delta: C^2(\mathbb R^2) \to C(\mathbb R^2)$. I have therefore added the tags pde and fa. This last question looks so natural that the answer should be known (and I believe it to be negative).

Comment: You may want to look at papers by Georges Papy from 1954.

Comment: I would like to have a look but it seems very difficult to get his papers. The title *Sur la réciproque du théorème de Volterra-Poincaré pour les formes à coefficients continus* suggests that it may be indeed relevant, but neither MR nor ZBl have an informative report on it.

Comment: On your edit: Problem 4.9 (a), page 71 of the book of Gilbarg and Trudinger, "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" (Springer-Verlag, 1998) provides a (counter)example of a continuous, compactly supported function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$, such that $\Delta u=f$ fails to have a $\mathscr{C}^2$ solution in any given open neighborhood of the origin. Therefore, $\Delta:\mathscr{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow\mathscr{C}^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: For a simpler example in the spirit of Gilbarg and Trudinger, you can take $u (x, y) = x y (\log x^2 + y^2)^\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and check that $\Delta u \in C (\mathbb{R}^2)$ but $u \not \in C^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)$. By classical regularity of the Laplacian, the difference between $u$ and another solution $\tilde{u}$ should be smooth and thus $\tilde{u} \not \in C^2 (\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Answer (score 12):

A proof of the Poincaré lemma with optimal regularity for (non-integer order) Hölder and (nonnegative-order $L^p$, $2\leq p<\infty$) Sobolev forms is provided by Theorem 8.3, pp. 148-149 of the book by G. Csató, B. Dacorogna and O. Kneuss, "The Pullback Equation for Differential Forms" (Birkhäuser, 2011). It states in the Hölder case ($k\geq 0$ an integer, $0<\alpha<1$) that the sequence $$ 0\rightarrow\mathscr{C}^{k+n,\alpha}(U,\wedge^0(\mathbb{R}^n))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathscr{C}^{k+n-1,\alpha}(U,\wedge^1(\mathbb{R}^n))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\cdots\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathscr{C}^{k+1,\alpha}(U,\wedge^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathscr{C}^{k,\alpha}(U,\wedge^n(\mathbb{R}^n))\rightarrow 0 $$ is exact for any $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open, bounded and contractible with smooth boundary (say, an open ball). The argument is actually quite similar to the one outlined by Igor in his answer (i.e. it uses a sharp version of the Hodge decomposition theorem), with appropriate care for the regularity gain in the above function spaces. It seems that it is also possible to provide a proof along more classical lines - the book quotes the PhD thesis of the first author for that, but I haven't got access to the thesis to check it yet.

The sequence made by the *first* two $d$ arrows even happens to be exact for $\alpha=0,1$ with the convention that $\mathscr{C}^{k,0}(U,\wedge^p(\mathbb{R}^n))=\mathscr{C}^k_b(\overline{U},\wedge^p(\mathbb{R}^n))$, by invoking instead Corollary 8.6, pp. 149-150 of the same book. One can derive from the above the exactness of the sequence $$ 0\rightarrow\mathscr{C}^{k+n,\alpha}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n,\wedge^0(\mathbb{R}^n))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathscr{C}^{k+n-1,\alpha}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n,\wedge^1(\mathbb{R}^n))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\cdots\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathscr{C}^{k+1,\alpha}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n,\wedge^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}\mathscr{C}^{k,\alpha}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n,\wedge^n(\mathbb{R}^n))\rightarrow 0 $$ if one uses an exhaustion of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by (say) closed balls centered at the origin, since Theorem 8.3 guarantees that for all *closed* $\eta\in\mathscr{C}^{k,\alpha}(U,\wedge^r(\mathbb{R}^n))$ there is $\omega\in\mathscr{C}^{k+1,\alpha}(U,\wedge^{r-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and a constant $C_{k,\alpha,U}>0$ such that $$d\omega=\eta\quad\text{with}\quad\|\omega\|_{\mathscr{C}^{k+1,\alpha}(U,\wedge^{r-1}(\mathbb{R}^n))}\leq C_{k,\alpha,U}\|\eta\|_{\mathscr{C}^{k,\alpha}(U,\wedge^{r}(\mathbb{R}^n))}$$ for all $r=1,\ldots,n$, $U$ as above. One can even have $\eta,\omega$ as above with $\alpha=0,1$ if $r=1$, so exactness of the first two $d$ arrows in the second sentence also holds with $\alpha=0,1$, despite the negative result regarding existence of $\mathscr{C}^2$ solutions of $\Delta u=f$ with continuous $f$ in my comment. The book does not mention the possibility of getting exactness for the whole first sequence with $\alpha=0,1$, but an inspection of the proof of Corollary 8.6 shows that one only needs Theorem 8.3 in the $L^p$ Sobolev case with $p>n$ sufficiently large together with Morrey's inequality in order to upgrade weak derivatives to classical derivatives. Therefore, I don't really see an obstacle for having exactness of the whole sequences above with $\alpha=0$ - if I understand correctly the argument, one just needs an appropriate version of Morrey's inequality for vector-valued functions instead.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this informative answer. The mentioned book lead me to find the answer to the question in the article of Preiss: There is in fact an obstacle for having exactness for $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Hmm, that's really interesting... I'll have a look at Preiss's paper to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to the question is in fact NO. It is quite surprising for me that it is relatively recent. Theorem 5 in the article *Additional regularity for solutions of PDE*
by David Preiss (J. reine angew. Math. 485 (1997), 197—207) states that there is a continuous function $\psi:\mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R$ with compact support such
that the equation
div$\Psi(x) = \psi (x) $ for almost every $x\in\mathbb R^2$
possesses no locally Lipschitz solution $\Psi:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$.

I thank Pedro Lauridsen Ribeiro and Igor Khavkine for their very informative comments. In particular, the book mentioned by Pedro eventually lead me to the article of Preiss.
(Unfortunately, I cannot split the bounty.)

Comment: I think the bounty should go to Pedro's answer, since it opened the path to the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks both to Jochen and Igor! The conclusion of Preiss's paper actually looks similar to that counterexample for the Laplacian in the book of Gilbarg-Trudinger. That's very interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Roughly, any regularity/support class of forms that can be smoothed in a translation invariant way, without leaving the same regularity/support class, still satisfies the Poincaré lemma. An explicit example, which uses a homotopy operator similar but not identical to the one in your question, can be found in de Rham's [original book](http://books.google.com/books?id=W41_MAEACAAJ) (Ch.3, §15), where he discusses smoothing of currents (distributional forms) to $C^\infty$ forms.

Smoothing can be achieved by convolution with a $C^\infty$ compactly supported bump function. This smoothing map can then be show to be homotopic to the inclusion $C^\infty \subset C^k \subset \mathscr{D}'$. Thus, the de Rham cohomology in $C^k$ is isomorphic to the one in $\mathscr{D}'$, which in turn is isomorphic to the one in $C^\infty$. So the Poincaré lemma holds for all of them.

---

**Update:** This is just to write in a bit more detail what I mentioned in the comments about using the inverse Laplacian to construct a contracting homotopy. I'm essentially appealing to a variant of Hodge theory. Let $\Delta = \partial^i\partial_i$ denote the standard Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I will denote the de Rham differential by $d$ and the co-differential by $\delta$, with explicit formulas $d[h]_{i_1\cdots i_k} = k\partial_{[i_1} h_{i_2\cdots i_k]}$ and $\delta[h]_{i_1\cdots i_k} = \partial^i h_{i i_1\cdots i_k}$. They satisfy the well-known identity $\Delta = \delta d + d\delta$, which means that $\delta$ can be thought of as a homotopy operator for the de Rham complex, inducing $\Delta$ as a null-homotopy morphism of the de Rham complex into itself.

Now, let $\Delta^{-1}$ be a Green function for $\Delta$. In other words, it is a translation invariant distribution $\Delta^{-1}(x-y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ that is smooth away from the diagonal and satisfies $\Delta_x \Delta^{-1}(x-y) = \delta^n(x-y)$ (Dirac delta). We can use the formula $\Delta^{-1}[h]_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x) = \int \Delta^{-1}(x-y) h_{i_1\cdots i_k}(x)$ to make it act on forms with compact support. By translation invariance, both $\Delta$ and $\Delta^{-1}$ commute with $d$ and $\delta$.

To extend the action of $\Delta^{-1}$ on forms of non-compact support, we need a smooth compactly supported bump function $\phi$ that is identically $1$ on a neighborhood $U\ni 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Later we'll also need a partition of unity $\sum_a \chi_a = 1$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, requiring that the supports of the $\chi_a$ are sufficiently small for each to fit into $U$ (perhaps with a safety margin) after a translation.

Let<sup>1</sup> $\Delta^{-1}_\phi[h](x) = \int \phi(x-y) \Delta^{-1}(x-y) h(y) dy$. This operator now has the following important properties: (a) it is still translation invariant, so $d\Delta^{-1}_\phi = \Delta^{-1}_\phi d$; (b) $\Delta^{-1}_\phi[h]$ is well defined even if $h$ does not have compact support, since the defining integral now has compact support for any fixed $x$ because of the factor of $\phi(x-y)$; (c) $\Delta^{-1}_\phi[\Delta[h]] = h$ for any $h$ with sufficiently small support, which applies in particular to any argument of the form $h=\chi_a g$.

Finally, let us define the homotopy operator<sup>2</sup> $H[h] = \Delta^{-1}_\phi[\delta h]$. It is now straight forward to verify the following identity for any $h$ with $d h = 0$:
$$
  d H[h] = \Delta^{-1}_\phi[d\delta h + \delta (d h)]
    = \Delta^{-1}_\phi[\Delta[h]]
    = \sum_a \Delta^{-1}_\phi[\Delta[\chi_a h]]
    = \sum_a \chi_a h
    = h .
$$

I think this actually answers the question, provided that $\Delta^{-1}[C^k_0] \subseteq C^{k+2}$, because then $H[C^k] \subset C^{k+1}$ and the homotopy works on the complex in question. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether that's true or not. I think it is true provided one uses some $C^{k,\alpha}$ Hölder class instead of $C^k$, though.

---

<sup>1</sup> Key phrase: *properly supported parametrix for the Laplacian*. 
<sup>2</sup> Key phrase: *properly supported parametrix for the de Rham complex*.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I am afraid that this does not answer the question where I want to have DIFFERENT differentiability classes at the spots of the sequence.

Comment: I think it's all the same. Suppose you pick different differentiability classes for forms of different degrees, say $C^{k_p}$ for $p$-forms. The main requirement is that $d C^{k_p} \subseteq C^{k_{p+1}}$. Then you still have the inclusions $C^\infty \subset C^{k_p} \subset \mathscr{D}'$, which respect $d$, and the smoothing homotopy takes care of the rest.

Comment: I do not understand: if $C^{k_p} \to C^{k_{p+1}} \to 0$ is exact (for $p+1=$ the dimension of the manifold, this is what we want) and $\ell_{p+1} < k_{p+1}$ the sequence $C^{k_p} \to C^{\ell_{p+1}} \to 0$ is certainly not exact.

Comment: I agree with Jochen. In particular, I see how to use the standard proof of the Poincaré lemma to get exactness if the same $k$ is used for every term in the sequence. But I don't see how to recover another order of differentiation when proving surjectivity of the last map in the 2d exact sequence given in the question.

Comment: Another thing to try are harmonic forms, but this fails, too.

Comment: You are of course both right. There's certainly something wrong with my abstract argument, but I've not yet had the time to dig into it and find the contradiction.

Comment: In the mean time, I can suggest a different homotopy operator, but I'm not completely sure of its gain in differentiability. Does the image of $C^k$ under $d \Delta^{-1}$ land in $C^{k-1}$ (where $\Delta^{-1}$ is the inverse Laplacian, defined arguments with compact support, b.c. going to $0$ at $\infty$, say)? If so, then a slight modification of the operator $d\Delta^{-1}$ (or is it ${*}d{*}\Delta^{-1}$...) provides the desired contracting homotopy (proving the desired version of the Poincaré lemma).

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the inverse Laplacian? In the case of $\mathbb R^2$, how should it map (a subspace of) $C(\mathbb R^2)$ to $C^1(\mathbb R^2)^2$?

Comment: That was meant to be explained in my cryptic parenthetical remark. :-) The integral kernel of $\Delta^{-1}$ should be a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$, smooth away from the diagonal. It acts as $\Delta^{-1}[h](x) = \int \Delta^{-1}(x,y) h(y) dy$ on functions with compact support. For the purposes of the Poincaré lemma, it can be extended to non-compactly supported arguments by smoothly truncating the integral kernel away from the diagonal. To get the homotopy operator, you need to compose it with $g \mapsto (\partial_2 g,-\partial_1 g)$.

Comment: Okay, I see. The question whether *"the image of $C^k$ under $d\Delta^{-1}$ lands in $C^{k-1}$"* is then equivalent (or at least very close to) the surjectivity of $\Delta: C^2 \to C$ (what you describe is the convolution with a fundamental solution, in our case a constant times $\log(x^2+y^2)$).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine unfortunately, the hypothesis you made in the last paragraph of your answer is not true (though I expect it to be true for Hölder classes, as you do). Please check my comment on Jochen Wengenroth's question...