# When is a `1-form' with continuous coefficients exact?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a convex, bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $C^1(\bar \Omega)$ be usual space of continuous functions on $\bar \Omega$ which are $C^1$ in $\Omega$ and whose partials in $\Omega$ are bounded and uniformly continuous in $\Omega$. My question is about the natural differentiation operator $D:C^1(\bar \Omega)\longrightarrow C(\bar \Omega)^d$, given by

$$
Du=(\partial_1u,\dots,\partial_du),
$$

where $\partial_i u$ is the unique extension to $\bar\Omega$ of the partial derivative of $u$ in the $e_i$ direction. My question is about the failure of surjectivity of $D$ when $d>1$: for which $f=(f_1,\dots,f_d)\in C(\bar \Omega)^d$ is there a $u\in C^1(\bar \Omega)$ such that $Du=f$?

There are (I think) some obvious necessary conditions concerning the relationship between the distributional derivatives of the $f_i$s if $f$ is to be `$D$ exact', and some restriction needs to be in effect to take care of what has to happen with line integrals. However, this question is a little outside my usual area of operation, so I thought I'd see if anyone know the answer. It occurs to me that there may be a connection with this question: [Poincare lemma for non-smooth differentiable forms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180451/poincare-lemma-for-non-smooth-differentiable-forms).

Comment: If I remember correctly, the answer is 'when the integral of the $1$-form $\phi$ along any two paths joining $p$ and $q$ has a value $F(p,q)=-F(q,p)$ that depends only on the endpoints $p$ and $q$'.  I think that there is also an answer based on $d\phi=0$ where the exterior derivative $d$ is suitably extended to the appropriate Sobolev spaces.

Comment: Ah. Thankyou for that! Can you suggest any relevant references?

Comment: Proposition 4.3.9 on page 334 in Horváth's *Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions* gives $\partial_i f_j=\partial_j f_i$ as a necessary and sufficient condition in the case $\Omega=\mathbb R\kern.4mm^n$ . Maybe the proof can be adapted to the case of bounded convex $\Omega$ ?

Comment: I will certainly investigate Horvath's book. Thanks!

Comment: @TaQ, note that Horváth's Prop.4.3.9 guarantees only that there exists a *distribution* $g$ such that $f_j = \partial_j g$. It does not guarantee that $g$ is $C^1$.

Comment: @DCM, your question is essentially the same question as the one you linked to, except with one level of regularity less. As the discussion there shows, this is a rather non-trivial question and the best available information seems fairly recent. So, if this question as posed is really of importance to you, you should look into that literature as cited there by Jochen and Pedro.

Comment: I was rather hoping that I had missed some subtle difference between my question and the one there which meant that mine had an easy answer... I will, however, do as you've suggested. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DCM: As people have pointed out, differential criteria are not adequate, but I'm not sure why you seem to be ignoring the integral condition, i.e., that, for $f_i$ continuous in $\Omega$, the $1$-form $\phi= f_i(x)\ dx^i$ is of the form $\phi = du$ for some $u \in C^1(\Omega)$ if and only if the integral of $\phi$ around any closed, piecewise $C^1$ path in $\Omega$  vanishes.  Is there some reason you don't like this criterion?

Comment: @RB: I'm not sure why the integral condition didn't appeal to me yesterday... (and sorry if you feel I dismissed your suggestion - this was certainly not my intention). It's certainly grown on me since I had a look at the alternative! Thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't the Poincare lemma hold for distributions? And if the weak derivatives of $u$ are continuous, it follows that $u$ is $C^1$.

Comment: I should say that I was perhaps overly pessimistic in my previous comment. Rereading the answer by Pedro at the linked question, I see that the obstacles to proving the Poincaré lemma at low regularities actually appear further along in the de Rham sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\ssp{\kern.4mm}
$Here is a sketch of proof of sufficiency of $d\ssp f=0$ , i.e. of $\partial_i f_j=\partial_j f_i$ (in the distributional sense) assuming that the case where $f$ is $C^1$ is known, for which I refer e.g. to the Poincaré lemma in §V.5 on pages 124−125  in Serge Lang's *Differential Manifolds*, Springer 1988.

Fix any $x_0\in\Omega$ , and define $u$ by $\Omega\owns x\mapsto\int_{\,0}^{\,1}f(x_0+t\,(x-x_0))\cdot(x-x_0)\,{\rm d\,}t$ . For fixed $x\in\Omega$ to prove that $d\ssp u(x)=f(x)$ , take a smooth "cut-off" function $\chi$ which has value $1$ up to "sufficiently" near to the boundary of $\Omega$ and which has value $0$ "very near" to the boundary. Further, take a "smooth bump" $\varphi$ at the origin with integral $1$ whose support is "very small". Let $\Omega_0$ be a convex open set with compact closure included in the interior of $\chi^{-1}[\{1\}]$ and $x_0,x\in\Omega_0$ and $\Omega_0-{\rm supp\,}\varphi\subset\chi^{-1}[\{1\}]$ . Then letting $g=(\chi\cdot f)*\varphi$ and defining $v$ by $\Omega\owns x\mapsto\int_{\,0}^{\,1}g\ssp(x_0+t\,(x-x_0))\cdot(x-x_0)\,{\rm d\,}t$ , by the $C^1$ or even the smooth case, noting that $\partial_i g_j=(\chi\cdot\partial_i f_j)*\varphi=(\chi\cdot\partial_j f_i)*\varphi=\partial_j g_i$ holds on $\Omega_0$ , we have $\partial_i v=g_i=(\chi\cdot f_i)*\varphi$ on $\Omega_0$ . Taking here in place of $\varphi$ the function $\varphi_n:z\mapsto n^d\ssp\varphi(n\ssp z)$ , and letting $n\to\infty$ , we get $\partial_i u=f_i$ pointwise on $\Omega_0$ since both convergences $g_i\ssp(\varphi_n)\to f_i$ and $v\ssp(\varphi_n)\to u$ as $n\to\infty$ are uniform on $\Omega_0$ . As $x\in\Omega$ here is arbitrarily fixed, we get $d\ssp u=f$ on $\Omega$ which further extends to the boundary by the assumed uniform continuity of $f$ .

Comment: This looks interesting too though (thanks TaQ!). I'll have a look in a second.

Comment: Very long second...

Comment: It was quite a long second. They have a habit of being longer than usual when I'm busy with other things... That is to say, sorry for the delay!